# How long have you lived here? how long have you been living here?

Tags: present-perfect, present-continuous

This question was said in a movie. A man asking a woman "how long have you lived here?" and they were having dinner.
I thought that he had to say "How long have you been living here?".

Comment: They were having dinner at her place.

Answer (score 2):

As a learner, I can say, based on my grammar book, that:

When we talk about situation that exists until the present, we can often use either the present perfect or present perfect continuous:

> We've been looking forward to this holiday for months.
>
> We've looked forward to this holiday for months.

It is worth to mention that, there are two main situations in which we use **present perfect continuous** rather **present perfect**:

1. We use present perfect continuous for suggesting repeated activity:

   > He has been kicking a football all day. (but, he has played in 54 national matches)
2. We use present perfect continuous for focusing on the process:

   > prices have been decreasing recently (but, prices have decreased by 4%)

Comment: We also use the present perfect continuous for recently completed actions: *Where have you been? I have been shopping for food*.